# How to get a value in another table, store it in a variable or data reader, and then use it to update another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, datareader

does anyone know how do I get the StudentID from Students table, store it in datareader or dataset, and then use it to update another table, which is Users Table, because I want the username and password of users would be their StudentID as a default. BTW, this is C# ASP.NET.
Here is my code.

```
    SqlConnection conUpdate = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    conUpdate.Open();

    SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand();
    com2.Connection = conUpdate;
    com2.CommandText = "SELECT Students.StudentID, Users.UserID FROM Students, Users " +
        "WHERE Students.UserID = Users.UserID";

    int UserId = ((int)com2.ExecuteScalar());

    com2.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(StudentID) FROM Students";

    int StudentId = ((int)com2.ExecuteScalar());

    com2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com2.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET UserName=@UserName, Password=@Password WHERE UserID=@UserID";

    com2.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    com2.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

    com2.Parameters[0].Value = reader;
    com2.Parameters[1].Value = reader;

    com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conUpdate.Close();
    conUpdate.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already getting UserId in your select query, you should get the value using DataReader. like this:

```
// Execute the query
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int UserId;
while(rdr.Read())
{
  UserId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["UserID"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command `com2.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(StudentID) FROM Students";` will return the Max student ID, and that is probably not needed. Your earlier command `com2.CommandText = "SELECT Students.StudentID, Users.UserID ....` is what you need to get the student UserID.

You can use [Data reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx) (Connection oriented) like below:

```
SqlDataReader reader = com2.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
     int UserId = Convert.ToInt(reader[0]);// or reader["UserID"]
}
reader.Close();
```

Or you can use [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) (disconnected mode) like:

```
SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(com2, connection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
a.Fill(dt);
```

Now your `dt.Rows["UserID"]` will have the UserID you need.

You may wanna see this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I think the following code might work. Or in the least give you an idea about how you can go about it. Am assuming that you want each student's UserName and Password to default to their StudentID

```
    SqlConnection conUpdate = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    conUpdate.Open();

    SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand();
    com2.Connection = conUpdate;
    com2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com2.CommandText = "SELECT Students.StudentID, Users.UserID FROM Students, Users " +
        "WHERE Students.UserID = Users.UserID";

    SqlDataReader reader = com2.ExecuteReader();

    if(reader != null)
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand();
            com3.Connection = conUpdate;
            com3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            com3.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET UserName=@UserName, Password=@Password WHERE UserID=@UserID";
            // Assuming that you need both the UserName and Password to default to StudentID
            com3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", reader.GetString(0)); // Assuming StudentID is NVARCHAR
            com3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", reader.GetString(0)); // Assuming StudentID is NVARCHAR
            com3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", reader.GetString(1)); // Assuming UserID is NVARCHAR
            com3.ExecuteNonQuery();                
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    conUpdate.Close();
```